# How much of the detailed complexities are needed for each initialization of Prism app?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, prism

How much of the detailed complexities are needed for each initialization of Prism app?

The high level view if things is that we have two classes:

```
1) UnityBootstrapper

2) MefBootstrapper
```

and based on experience and context you need to decide which one to use. What the bootstrapper
does for you is to create the main window, also called the shell, and other secondary things.
The problem is that there are many other complicated details in this process. What should I use,
what should I ignore, it is incredibly confusing? How did you guys start? For the experienced folks,
do you care today about the details of the initialization process, or for the most part you still
don't know what is going on and you just use some old template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an idea, here is one of my MEF bootstrappers of an application which I consider to be quite complex. It's straight forward, nothin really hard to understand. In the background, there's a lot more to it, like custom region behaviors, adapters and the whole MEF exporting stuff.

```
public class MainBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
   protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Logging.ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
   {
       return new Log4NetLogger();
   }
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        var currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? "";
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(currentFolder));
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(currentFolder + Settings.Default.ElementsFolder));
    }

    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        var mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(RadPaneGroup), new RadPaneGroupRegionAdapter(ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()));
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(Menu), new MenuRegionAdapter(ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()));
        return mappings;
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        var shellWindow = (Shell) Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow = shellWindow;
        shellWindow.Show();
        shellWindow.InjectInitialViews();
    }

    protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
    {
        ViewModelInjectionBehavior.RegionsToAttachTo.Add(RegionNames.ElementViewRegion);

        var behaviorFactory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
        behaviorFactory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior));
        behaviorFactory.AddIfMissing("AutoPopulateExportedMenuItemsBehavior", typeof(AutoPopulateExportedMenuItemsBehavior));
        behaviorFactory.AddIfMissing("ElementViewInjectionBehavior", typeof(ViewModelInjectionBehavior));
        return behaviorFactory;
    }
}
```

I have never really worked with Unity. Unity requires explicit configuration which I'm not a fan of for laziness reasons, MEF can be a PITA to debug, if it doesn't behave as expected.

If you melt it down to what you really need, when building your first PRISM app, the bootstrapping sequence becomes even easier, because you don't need to register custom mappings and custom behaviors.

```
public class MainBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        var currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? "";
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(currentFolder));            
    }        

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        var shellWindow = (Shell) Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow = shellWindow;
        shellWindow.Show();
        shellWindow.InjectInitialViews();
    }        
}
```

There is no boiler plate code at all, so nothing that would require code templates. or that is hard to understand. As always: Use as little as you can and as much as you need. If you feel that you need additional functionality or a more complex configuration, a fancy logging mechanism, custom regions, etc., etc., you can extend your code, but I recommend to focus on the core things for now.